# VT-x is Enabled, but is not operational ? Winows 8 unable to run 64-bit virtual machine

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization, vmware-workstation

Vt-x is Enabled in  Bios and it shows working in Intel Processor identification utility.
but I'm not able to run 64-bit Guest OS on both VirtualBox & VMware Workstation.

Virtual Box says

> VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration has been enabled, but is not operational. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot.

PS : I have not enabled the Windows 8 Hyper-v feature

Comment: What OEM are you using?   There is a glitch where if you enable Virtualization Technolgy it actually disables it.  What processor are you using?

Comment: Update to the latest BIOS for your system. Update to the latest VirtualBox. Shut the system all the way off and then back on. Make sure "trusted execution" is *off* in your BIOS. Make sure you're not running any other virtualization software. See if the problem persists.

Comment: which CPU do you use?

Comment: Is the host 64Bit enabled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VT-x is enabled, but it's not detected as such](https://superuser.com/questions/963392/vt-x-is-enabled-but-its-not-detected-as-such)

Answer (score 0):

Avast 2015 with its option "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" was the root cause of the fact that VT-x was disabled in Windows 7 for me ;-P Disable it and restart fixed my trouble.