# VT-x is enabled, but it's not detected as such

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vt-x

I preemptively reinstalled Windows 7 Ultimate x64 recently, but I lost the ability to use VT-x in the process. Namely, I was trying to get HAXM to work, but I will surely need it later for VirtualBox. It's enabled in the BIOS, but several programs detect it as available, but disabled.

Before this, VirtualBox worked normally and, since the first time that I ran a virtual Android device, HAXM was installed and running without needing a dedicated installation. My hardware didn't changed between VT-x working and not working.

Here's what I got after some searching:

I tested with NX bit enabled and disabled.

I tested disabling VT-x, restarting, enabling it starting again.

I removed "Tablet PC Components" from Windows Features.

Avast's "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" is checked.

None of these made VT-x work again. Both HAXM's installation and Microsoft's HAV Detection Tool say VT-x is available but disabled. I have no other virtualization technology installed. Also, just for curiosity, I made a test on Xubuntu 14.04. Running `rdmsr 0x3A` returns 5.

CPU: Intel Core i3-2100

Motherboard: Gigabyte H61M-S1

So, what do I have to do to make VT-x work again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just confirming that you don't have any other virtualization technologies running - Hyper-V isn't installed/enabled? I ended up running two configs on my boxes - one with Hyper-V and one without so I could run HAXM

On one of my boxes I ended up having to disable VT-x, power off and remove power for 30 seconds, re-enable VT-x, power off and remove power for 30 seconds and it came good.

Comment: I certainly didn't installed Hyper-V, and it doesn't show up as an uninstallable program. It could have been installed without my knowledge (programatically), but that''s unlikely. I tried your method but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=162445.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Avast, go to -> *Settings* -> *Troubleshooting* -> "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization", and uncheck Avast's "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization". Source: https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=162445.0

Answer (score 0):

Installing VirtualBox solved the issue. I just didn't do this before because I thought I would need to solve the VT-x problem first, but I had another more urgent problem which required VirtualBox so I did it.

Comment: The "issue" is that only one application can use VT-x at a time and you have told Avast to use it.